# Series Coefficient Convergence implies Uniform Convergence

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Trying to find a reference for the following.

Define the entire functions, $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k}x^k\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k.$$ If for each $k$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,k} =a_k$, then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly on compact sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not true.  Try $f_n(x) = x^n$ and $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Oh my ****. Three months ago, I was scrutinized for not knowing this "obvious" fact. :-(

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

It is true if $(f_n)$ is a bounded family, that is, uniformly bounded on compact sets. Use Montel's theorem and the following fact: if from every subsequence of $(f_n)$ you can extract another subsequence that converges to $f$, then $f_n$ converges to $f$.

Comment: Not sure why you wrote "HINT". I wasn't asking for a hint or proof or homework problem alternative, I was asking for a reference and apparently none exists. Very frustrating.

Comment: The proposition as stated is not correct, as the counterexample in the other answer shows. The hint is about the fact that  you can still modify a bit the statement to make it correct.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is more out of frustration. Nothing really to do with you.